# How to change font size in Rails Prawn PDF gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I have the following code to generate a table in pdf :

```
  def member_list
    move_down 20
    table member_list_rows do
      self.row(0).align = :center
      row(0).background_color = '3498db'
      row(0).text_color = "FFFFFF"
      self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
      self.header = true
    end
  end
```

In here, how can I change the font size in the table cells? I tried many methods (style, font_size, size) nothing works! What is the correct way?

Comment: Give this a try: `cell.style size: 20`, where `20` is the font size.

Comment: @vee It says `undefined local variable or method `cell' for #<Prawn::Table:0x00000006555a68>`

Comment: Oh no no, I meant that `cell` to be your table cell.

Comment: @vee sorry didn't understand you. where should i put that line?

Comment: Try `row(0).columns(0).style size: 20` basically anywhere within the `table` block.

Comment: @vee thanks it changed the size of the first cell. How to do it for the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Prawn manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) under `table/cell_text.rb` you can find

```
table data, :cell_style => { :size => 18, :text_color => "346842" }
```

You can style a host of other things except for the size as you see.

Comment: How to do it in this do block?

Comment: As I cannot find any reference to `member_list_rows` in the Prawn documentation I guess this is a method you wrote yourself to provide your `data`. Add the `, :cell_style => { }` hash after your `end` of block and it should work.

Comment: I see, the block does not bind to the `member_list_rows` but to the `table` which has an initializing block. In the Prawn docs I found `cells.style(:width => 24, :height => 24)` in such a block (in `table/style.rb`). This lets it seem reasonable that you may set the cell size in the same way.